# Как из ответа API вывести данные в чисто м виде а не ссылками js Нужны данные про people с этими id?

Tags: javascript

```
const API_URL =  "https://swapi.dev/api/films/2/";
getMovies(API_URL);
async function getMovies(url) {
  const resp = await fetch(url);
  const respData = await resp.json();
  console.log(respData);
return respData
}
```

> вывод  characters: Array(16) 0: "https://swapi.dev/api/people/1/" 1:
> "https://swapi.dev/api/people/2/" 2: "https://swapi.dev/api/people/3/"
> 3: "https://swapi.dev/api/people/4/" 4:
> "https://swapi.dev/api/people/5/" 5:
> "https://swapi.dev/api/people/10/" 6:
> "https://swapi.dev/api/people/13/" 7:
> "https://swapi.dev/api/people/14/" 8:
> "https://swapi.dev/api/people/18/" 9:
> "https://swapi.dev/api/people/20/" 10:
> "https://swapi.dev/api/people/21/"`введите сюда код` 11:
> "https://swapi.dev/api/people/22/" 12:
> "https://swapi.dev/api/people/23/" 13:
> "https://swapi.dev/api/people/24/" 14:
> "https://swapi.dev/api/people/25/" 15:
> "https://swapi.dev/api/people/26/"

Comment: что такое "чистый вид"?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я могу сделать запрос API только про фильм (одну из частей , это звездные войны), либо сделать запрос на API про всех персонажей, а мне нужно получить данные про персонажей из второго фильма, а ответ про персонажей приходит в виде ссылок, а не данных про них, как получить данные я не понимаю, кто может помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Пройтись циклом запросов по полученным ссылкам?

Comment: т.е forEach  и  в нем async

Comment: Ничего не выходит

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

```js
const API_URL = "https://swapi.dev/api/films/2/";
async function getData(url) {
  const resp = await fetch(url);
  const respData = await resp.json();
  return respData;
}
async function getCharacters() {
  const movie = await getData(API_URL);
  let charactersPromises = [];
  for (ch in movie.characters) {
    charactersPromises.push(getData(movie.characters[ch]));
  }
  const charactersList = await Promise.all(charactersPromises);
  console.log(charactersList);
  return charactersList;
}
getCharacters();
```

Comment: Большое спасибо